# How to Increment number per Item and ID in a data entry form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new with Google sheets with app script, I am trying to increment the ID and per item entered using data entry.

Data entry form:
[image]

below is my code.

```
function btn_StockAvailableSubmit(){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
//-----------Declarations
const id_Num = formSettings.getRange(2,13)
const next_IDNum = id_Num.getValue()
const fld_FundClusterGrpCode = formMain.getRange("H6").getValue() //Main sheet field RIS Group ID Code
const fld_FundCluster = formMain.getRange("H7").getValue() //The Cluster Fund Name

const fld_Year = formSettings.getRange("F3").getValue()
const fld_ClusterCodeRegular = formSettings.getRange("G3").getValue()
const fld_ClusterCodeSeatbelt = formSettings.getRange("G4").getValue()
const fld_ClusterCodeInfra = formSettings.getRange("G5").getValue()
//----------
//-----------Regular Fund
//Get values
const id_RegularFundCluster = formSettings.getRange("H3") //Settings sheet Regular field RIS Group ID Code
const id_RegularFundClusterPerItem = formSettings.getRange("J3") //Settings sheet Regular field RIS Per Item Code
const nextID_RegularFundCluster = id_RegularFundCluster.getValue()
const nextID_RegularFundClusterPerItem = id_RegularFundClusterPerItem.getValue()
var ssLastRow = formMain.getLastRow();
var ssLastColumn = formMain.getLastColumn()-1
var ssData = formMain.getRange(11, 2, ssLastRow - 10, ssLastColumn).getValues()
//need to find TRUE to count all TRUE!

for(var i=nextID_RegularFundClusterPerItem;i > ssData.length;i++){
    //
}

if(fld_FundCluster == "Regular Fund"){
    //console.log(ssData[i][4])
    ssData.map(x => {
      if(x[4] == true){
        var zeros = "00000000000000000000000"
        var concatenateRegularFundIDPerItem = fld_Year +"-"+ fld_ClusterCodeRegular +"-"+ [zeros.substring(-1, 5 - i.toString().length) + i++]
        var id = i - 1
        x.unshift(id, deDate, deEntityName, deOffice); x.push(dateApproved,fld_FundClusterGrpCode,fld_Year,fld_ClusterCodeRegular,nextID_RegularFundCluster,concatenateRegularFundIDPerItem)
        db_Requisition.appendRow(x); //Transfer data
      }
    });
  }

//--------Increment Group IDs
id_Num.setValue(i)

if(fld_FundCluster == "Regular Fund"){     
  id_RegularFundCluster.setValue(nextID_RegularFundCluster+1)
  id_RegularFundClusterPerItem.setValue(i)
}
```

RESULT (db_Requisition form):

[image]

The output in "ID" Column and "RIS ID
(PER ITEM AND CLUSTER)" is correct but, the next time I submit another form, it does not stop running. Then after a few minutes, the error "maximum error time".

*Please bear with my codes*
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think your loop condition is wrong. It currently continues while I is greater than ssData.length. You are incrementing s so if that's ever true it's going to carry on until I overflows.

Comment: @digby280, hi, thank you. Yes partly, I knew that somehow, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I tried to delete the for loop and just inserted a variable for the ID and Per Item ID and just inserted variable++ for it to be incremented. Well it worked, for now, I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the for loop and just assigned a variable and incremented it and it worked.

I declared the var `z` and `i` outside the `if` statement.

Here's my code:

```
var z = next_IDNum
var i = nextID_RegularFundClusterPerItem

if(fld_FundCluster == "Regular Fund"){
ssData.map(x => {
  if(x[4] == true){
    var zeros = "00000000000000000000000"
    var concatenateRegularFundIDPerItem = fld_Year +"-"+ fld_ClusterCodeRegular +"-"+ [zeros.substring(-1, 5 - i.toString().length) + i++]
    var id = z++
    x.unshift(id, deDate, deEntityName, deOffice); x.push(dateApproved,fld_FundClusterGrpCode,fld_Year,fld_ClusterCodeRegular,nextID_RegularFundCluster,concatenateRegularFundIDPerItem)
    db_Requisition.appendRow(x); //Transfer data
  }
});
}

//--------Increment Group IDs

if(fld_FundCluster == "Regular Fund"){
  id_Num.setValue(i)
  id_RegularFundCluster.setValue(nextID_RegularFundCluster+1)
  id_RegularFundClusterPerItem.setValue(i)
}
```